# how to handle Enter key in between the string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a string `Text` which has enter key values in between the string. While retrieving the value in JavaScript I do like this:

```
text = "${value.text}";
```

If I have a text where user uses Enter key to type text in next line the words they enter after pressing enter key is not displaying properly showing me error `Unterminated string`. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: How does the user input the text? How to you retrieve that text?

Comment: It depends.  The ${value.text} field looks like it's filled in by serverside page-generation.  PHP or ASP or summat.  Is that correct?

Comment: Its a  magnolia text field i retrive from magnolia(CMS) and display in jsp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you mean, but the unterminated string literal error can occur when you've written a string like this:

```
var str = " a bit of the string here
            another here";
```

by mistake, as this isn't valid Javascript, you need to:

```
var str = " a bit of the string here \n" + 
          " another here";
```

Comment: That's in JavaScript source code. The OP has text entered by the user.

Comment: That shouldn't cause an issue, since the break put in by the user should be encoded as the newline character in the string itself.  Unless I'm missing something!  Do you have an working example of what you mean?

Comment: My text is coming like the above code var str = "abit of string  here so the first line doesn't end with double quotes javascript throws error to me unterminated string. Its not considering the new line another here"; which is in the next line

Comment: Just to get it straight - by "user entered text" are you are actually talking about the Javascript source code having breaks in it (since you're generating it dynamically server side)?  If so, I think you might need to strip out the newlines characters in the `${value.text}` bit and replace then with the literal 2 characters: `"\n"` (i.e. a slash followed by an `n`).